# Can I have extra row in datatable not used for mapping

Tags: carto

Is there a way that I can disregard 1 row in the table when generating a map and its Jenks values?

We have the need to create separate tables and charts from the data we are mapping.  There needs to be an extra row of data in the data-table for the tables/charts.  But this won’t be included in the map or the Jenks values we’re using for a custom legend.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options depending on the particulars of your use-case.

**option 1**

Visualizations are pulled dynamically from tables. So, if you are generating tables/charts from a table of data, it doesn't matter what you do in a Visualization. So, just create a new visualization and filter out the single datapoint from your table before you calculate Jenks,

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE cartodb_id != {{the id of your single row}}
```

Now, apply the jenks and it should only be calculated on the filtered dataset, while any API requests to the table will still access all the data.

**option 2**

Use 2 tables with the same schema. One containing the single row, the other containing all the rest. Then, create your maps from the single dataset. For your tables and charts, perform a UNION statement to bring them together dynamically.

```
SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom, name, description FROM table_one
UNION ALL
SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom, name, description FROM table_two
```

**option 3**

Calculate the jenks without the single row, then add it back in after you know the style. To do this, perform a filter query,

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE cartodb_id != {{the id of your single row}}
```

Select the style and Jenks to get your map. Now, the values returned by the Jenks calculation are really only stored in the CartoCSS, so copy your CartoCSS and put it in an empty text document for a minute.

Next, clear your query statement so you have the full dataset again. This might void the style. If it does, just go back to the CartoCSS editor on your map and apply the style you have in your text file.